# Separating responsibilities with boundaries in SOA

Tags: soa

I have two API/Services. One is a **TaxServiceAPI** which is integrated with a few third-party service called **ThirdPartyTaxAPI** to get tax quote. The other service is a **BillingServiceAPI**. The **BillingServiceAPI** has an internal product number (eg. BOOK0001) for which a tax quote has to be received from the **TaxServiceAPI**. The problem is that the **TaxServiceAPI** knows only the products being used in the third-party service **ThirdPartyTaxAPI**. The product numbers in **ThirdPartyTaxAPI** don't match with the internal company products numbers. The corresponding product number for BOOK0001 in **ThirdPartyTaxAPI** is 10005.

Because there is no matching of the product numbers, I have to map BOOK0001 to 10005 either in the **BillingServiceAPI** or **TaxServiceAPI**. By considering the SOA principles, where should I do the mapping? Should I put it in **BillingServiceAPI** or **TaxServiceAPI**? I can't decide who's responsibility is to map the internal company products to the products that third party API uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the TxtServiceAPI is your service that interacts with the 3rd party API. In which case, it makes sense that it would hold the translation as its role it to bridge your internal world to the external one whereas internal services don't care about that data